# How to make a string array?

Tags: python

How do I make a string array in python with length 100 for example. I don't use python much so I'm not really sure how. I want the array to be formatted in this way so I can assign a string to a value in a separate line.

```
keyword = [100]
keyword[0] = "Blue Light Glasses"
keyword[1] = "Tech Fleece Joggers"
```

Comment: You can use something like `[None] * 100` and then reassign elements as necessary.

Comment: If you don't need random access for construction, just `keyword = []` then `keyword.append(string)` as needed.  Or if the strings are known in advance, just `keyword = ['string1','string2']`.

Comment: I’ll add that this is something that is rarely needed in Python. It feels like an xy problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you fix the lenght of the array, you can just create a list with a none value

```
keyword = [''] * 100   # list of 100 element
keyword[0] = 'Blue Light Glasses'
keyword[1] = "Tech Fleece Joggers"
```

You can also create a empty list and add element in this list

```
keyword = list()
keyword.append('Blue Light Glasses')
keyword.append('Tech Fleece Joggers')
print(keyword)
```

Output:

```
['Blue Light Glasses', 'Tech Fleece Joggers']
```

Comment: The output could also be used as the way to create the "array" in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

there isn't a way in python to declare a array of a fixed lenght but there are some "tricks" to do this as:

```
lenght = 100
# You are creating an array of 100 None items
listOfNone = [None] * lenght
```

Another thing you can't do is declare an array of that fixed value type (like string). **You can create an array only made of string but at any time you could replace a string element of the array with an int for example.**
Here is an example:

```
lenght = 100
# Declaring an array made of 100 "a beautiful string" repeating
listOfStrings = ["a beautiful string"] * lenght 
# Replacing the tenth element with a 12 (type int)
listOfStrings[9] = 12
# You can check the type of the element in python by printing:
print(type(listOfStrings[9])) # This will print int
print(type(listOfStrings[8])) # This will print string. As you can see there are 2 types of var in the same list (python doesn't matter)
listOfStrings[24] = False #Placing a bool in the 25th element
```

There is a workaround to this: you can create a function that handles the array (or use a class too, but I don't know your Python level).
I'm typing a basic function for you that you can adjust for your needs

```
def fillArrayWithElement(array, element):
    if not str(type(array)) == "<class 'list'>":
        # The array is not an array
        raise ValueError('The first parameter must be list type')
        return
    if not str(type(prova2)) == "<class 'str'>":
        # The element to add is not a string
        raise ValueError('The element must be str type')
        return
    array.append(element)
    return array
```